# A question about itemize and figures

Tags: itemize

When i use a figure alone (and nothing more) in an itemize environment as in the sample code

```
\item[11.7]

\begin{center}
\includegraphics [width=9cm]{code-page629.eps}
\end{center}
```

the numbering (11.7 in this case) is printed in the bottom left corner. Is it possible to print the numbering in the top left corner? (see the attached figure). I do not provide a MWE since there is no need to run something, it is actually a "theoretical" question .. thanks a lot ![image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble and `valign=t` into the optional argument of `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Depending on the overall purpose of this, there is most likely a better way to achive the desired output. e.g. the `center` environment doe not only center the image but also changes the horizontal position of the number. Lastly, the combination of an `itemize` environment with a manually numbered item seems a bit strage.

Comment: How is it a theoretical question if you have existing code and an image?  Regardless, even if the question were truly theoretical, providing a MWE would give everyone something to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix that simply corrects this is to place an invisible character `\strut` after the item:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item Premier
   \item Second
   \item[11.7]\strut
      \begin{center}
      \includegraphics [width=9cm]{example-image}
      \end{center}
   \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked and this is exactly what I want .. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

Without `adjustbox`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\itemimg#1#2{\item[#1]\leavevmode\vskip-\baselineskip\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\itemimg{11.7}{example-image-a}
\itemimg{11.8}{example-image-b}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

BTW, If all the images are like simple tables, consider type the tables directly, that is:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
    11.7 & YY & EQU & ... & ...  \\
         & SAVEX & EQU & ... & ...  \\ 
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea, why you would want to do this and there are definitely better ways to do this,
but what you need to know is that the referencepoint of an image in Tex is always the lower left corner. So what you need to do is wrap your picture in a box to get the reference into the upper left corner.

`\usepackage{adjustbox}` should be the way to go. look up the vertical alignment.

here ist an example, which also centers it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[11.7] \adjustbox{width=9cm,center,valign=t}{\includegraphics{code-page629.eps}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you might also want to take a look at the `Listing` package, if your representing code snippets in your document

Comment: If you use `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` you can directly add the `valign` option to the `\includegraphics` command as follows: `\includegraphics [width=9cm, valign=t]{code-page629.eps}`